# Отправка письма из Java из домена

Tags: email, api, java-8, javamail

Как можно отправить письмо из домена? Например, log@stal.ru, или что-то в этом 
духе. Домен расположен на серверах яндекса.
При попытке отправить показывает такие сообщения:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 

javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.yandex.ru", port 995, isSSL false
```

Вот мой код:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//Enable tls session
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");//Enable authentication
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yandex.ru");//Server's host
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "995");//Server's port

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("name@domain.ru", "password102030");
                }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);


try {

    Scanner to = new Scanner(toWho);
    while (to.hasNextLine())
    {
        String touser = to.nextLine();

    try {
         if (howMany <= batch)
    {
        howMany++;
        System.out.println("Задержка "+delayevery/1000+" секунд");
        Thread.sleep(delayevery);
    }
    else
    {
        howMany = 0;
        System.out.println("Задержка "+delaybatch/1000+" секунд");
        Thread.sleep(delaybatch);
    }
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username,alias));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(touser));
        message.setSubject(subject);


         // Create the message part
 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 BodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();

 if (image != "")
 imagePart.setContent("<img src=\""+image+"\">","text/html");
 // Now set the actual message
 messageBodyPart.setText(MailSender.message);

 // Create a multipar message
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
 //Set image message part
 multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
 // Set text message part
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 // Part two is attachment
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

 if (attaching != "")      
  {
 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attaching);
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

 messageBodyPart.setFileName(javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encodeWord(source.getName(),
        "UTF-8", null));
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  }
 // Send the complete message parts
 message.setContent(multipart);


        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done "+(++counter));

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.print("База была не найдена.");
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.print("Что-то неверно.");
}
```

}

Comment: Вряд ли SMTP сервер принимает соединения на порту 995: он обычно используется для POP3+SSL. Попробуйте 465 или 587.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, надо было просто включить ssl сессию:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

Comment: В таком случае примите свое решение

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помогло сменить порт с 465 на 587